# Using the result of subquery to update a table also referred to in the subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1093

I'm trying to fix an incomplete database where I don't have control over the schema and I need to find missing entries and insert them.

This is syntax I've arrived at:

```
INSERT INTO 
  downloads (product_id, filename)
VALUES 
( 
  products_id = ( SELECT id
         FROM products 
         WHERE id NOT IN
           ( SELECT product_id
             FROM downloads
           )
       ), 
  filename = 'default.zip'
)
```

The subquery works fine alone but the above throws an error

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'download' for update in FROM clause
```

I've reviewed many of the StackOverflow questions related to this error ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)), and I gather that there is a way to nest a subquery such that it "[creates an implicit temporary table, so it doesn't count as the same table you're updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/45498#45498)" but I haven't been able to adapt it.

If my approach is inefficient that's OK, I'm very curious to see a solution that get's close to my syntax but any solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to do,

- use `INSERT...INTO SELECT` statement
- use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `NOT IN`
- don't forget to add index on this columns: `products.ID` and `downloads.product_id` for faster performance

query,

```
INSERT INTO  downloads (product_id, filename)
SELECT  a.id AS product_id, 'default.zip' AS filename
FROM    products a
        LEFT JOIN downloads b
            ON a.ID = b.product_id
WHERE   b.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. My lack of understanding about the meaning of `IS NULL` lead me to the nested subquery solution.